# Show div only if post is in specific category

Tags: categories, loop

In my list of blog posts, I would like to show a div which labels the post as a "Press Release" if the post is tagged with the "Press" category.

I have added the following chunk into my loop:

```
<?php if (is_category( 'press' )) : ?><div class="category">Press Release</div><?php endif;?>
```

I have also tried replacing `press` with the category ID, but neither seem to work. Is this how I should be implementing this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`is_category()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category) does this:

> (...) Checks if a Category archive page is being displayed. (...)

One line below on the codex page you find:

> To test if a post is in a category use [`in_category()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category).

So just use the latter.